# ElasticSearch DSL Matching all elements of query in list of list of strings

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to query ElasticSearch to match every document that in a list of list contains all the values requested, but I can't seem to find the perfect query.

Mapping:

```
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "mainlist" : {
          "properties" : {
            "format" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "tags" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
```

Documents:

```
doc1 {
   "id" : "abc",
   "mainlist" : [
            {
              "type" : "big",
              "tags" : [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
              ]
             },
             {
              "type" : "small",
              "tags" : [
                "tag1"
              ]
             }
    ]
},
doc2 {
   "id" : "abc",
   "mainlist" : [
            {
              "type" : "big",
              "tags" : [
                "tag1"
              ]
             },
            {
              "type" : "small",
              "tags" : [
                "tag2"
              ]
             }
    ]
},
doc3 {
   "id" : "abc",
   "mainlist" : [
            {
              "type" : "big",
              "tags" : [
                "tag1"
              ]
             }
    ]
}
```

The query I've tried that got me closest to the result is:

```
GET /index/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mainlist.tags": "tag1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "mainlist.tags": "tag2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

although I get as result `doc1` and `doc2`, while I'd only want `doc1` as contains tag1 and tag2 in a single list element and not spread across both sublists.

How would I be able to achieve that?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please go through my answer and let me know if you need more infomartion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @caster, you need to use the [nested data type and query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) as in normal way Elasticsearch treats them as object and relation between the elements are lost, as explained in [offical doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

You need to change both mapping and query to achieve the desired output as shown below.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "mainlist" :{
                "type" : "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Index doc according to your example, no change there**

**Query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "mainlist",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "mainlist.tags": "tag1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "mainlist.tags": "tag2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And result**

```
hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71519931_new",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.9139043,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "abc",
                    "mainlist": [
                        {
                            "type": "big",
                            "tags": [
                                "tag1",
                                "tag2"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "small",
                            "tags": [
                                "tag1"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit, that's very helpful, as mentioned in the comment to Caster , I was looking to a solution, even using scripting to addressing it in a "non-nested" structure, but will plan a full reindex with "nested"

Answer (score 0):

use nested field type，this is work for it
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/nested.html

Comment: thanks! I have some other blocks with Nested type that I was able to query, but I was wondering if it was possible without the "nesting", perhaps using a Painless script, as I won't be able to reindex everything as Nested at the moment.
But is definitely the proper solution, I agree. 
Thanks for confirming it @caster